# Deleting files from signed java applet

Tags: java, applet, sign

I have to delete some temporary file from a users system when he logs out of application. The application has applet. The applet jar is signed. I am following the strategy to call the applet's destroy method to delete files. I am invoking the destroy method of applet by **javascript** 
like  **document.myApplet.destroy()** . After invoking this I am getting the error on browser as

**Uncaught Error: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.io.FilePermission Uncaught Error: Error calling method on NPObject.**

Comment: I think that your destroy method is private or something.

Comment: No my destory method is not private and I found that it is not getting called by chrome when user is signing out !

Comment: But it is for other browsers?

Comment: Please see my code  :  public void destroy() {
 String tempFolder = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
 String cacheFolder = tempFolder+"/AppCache"; 
 File file = new File(cacheFolder);
 if(file.exists() && file.isDirectory()){
  deleteDirectory(cacheFolder);
 }
  
}

Comment: Your code is impeccable, as long as `deleteDirectory` does what it is supposed to do.

Comment: deleteDirectory does the right job. Still the same results . Please help !!

Comment: do you get the error if you run the applet in another browser which remembers to call `destroy()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I got the answer myself: After refering to this link http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/AccessController.html , I figured out ,that reading,writing or even deleting can be done by wraping them up in AccessController.doPrivileged method.

```
AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction() {

                @Override
                public Object run() {
                    try {
                        deleteAppCacheDirectory();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return null;
                }

            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the call to the `destroy` method from your javascript code. The destroy method is automatically called by the browser when the user leaves the page. The reason this is happening is probably because your `destroy` method is not public. This doesn't prevent the browser from calling it, however.