# Delete java cache programmatically

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I am loading applet in the browser and I want to delete the cache at the start of an applet. The applet stores its cache information in `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\cache`. I did not find much information on how to delete the cache using java program. And I referred some link that said to use  `Config.getCacheDirectory()` but no luck on that too.

Please let me know if you have any other approach to delete the cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access the file system of the client through an applet. Not unless the applet is signed with a certificate by a trusted authority.

Comment: My applet is signed by trusted authority. But how do you get location of cache in the java program. One approach I figured to use Config.get().getCacheDirectory() this isnt helping me. I also referred this http://stackoverflow.com/a/18056234/431714. But no luck.